# When is best to buy an ENS domain?

Tags: ens

I was wondering if it would be best to buy an ENS domain before or after the merge. Right now I can get one for 10 years at $50, but have to spend $148 is gas. Would ETH 2.0 make it $50 + a few dollars for gas, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The merge will not decrease gas fees](https://blockster.com/blockdesk/2151_the-ethereum-merge-won-t-lower-fees-so-what-will). However there may be other proposals and changes before or after the merge that change fees, plus network traffic will have an effect. Overall gas fees may decrease within a few years but it's impossible to tell for certain.

Comment: Oh I had no idea they weren't decreasing gas fees... I thought that was the main plan for eth2...

Comment: ETH2 will switch to PoS, which might change the dynamic and might allow a higher throughput when combined with other changes. But as mentioned in the post all of this is no guarantee for a lower gas price, as the demand might also increase.